# Google Charts API "Uncaught Error: one or more fonts could not be loaded."

Tags: javascript, charts

I'm embedding a chart made with Google's visualization API on my site. In doing so, I've put the following code in an iframe as a file called chart.html:

```
<html>
  <body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['bar']}]}"></script>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
    <br/>
    <script type='text/javascript'> ... a whole bunch of Google Chart code which produces a bar, column or line visualization ... </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This works perfectly fine on JS Fiddle, but does not work on my chart.html file, instead I get an error that says "one or more fonts could not be loaded" from a file that Google Charts API includes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Google Charts API *for some visualizations* requires a `<head></head>` element on the page. When it goes to load fonts - they are necessary whether you have instructed it to or not - it tries to append some font references to your header, but since your head is missing, it throws that error and then renders nothing in the chart's place.

It is easily fixed by adding a head element right after your HTML tag.

Answer (score 0):

no need to put on head, check use below code it's work in chat.html file

```
<html>
 <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','version':'1.1','packages':['bar']}]}"></script>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
    <br/>
     <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ["Element", "Density", { role: "style" } ],
        ["Copper", 8.94, "#b87333"],
        ["Silver", 10.49, "silver"],
        ["Gold", 19.30, "gold"],
        ["Platinum", 21.45, "color: #e5e4e2"]
      ]);

      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      view.setColumns([0, 1,
                       { calc: "stringify",
                         sourceColumn: 1,
                         type: "string",
                         role: "annotation" },
                       2]);

      var options = {
        title: "Density of Precious Metals, in g/cm^3",
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},
        legend: { position: "none" },
      };
      var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById("chart_div"));
      chart.draw(view, options);
  }
  </script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

This error is caused because Google Charts API js "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js" automatically loads "fonts.css" file for creation of graphs and if it finds one already existing it throws this error in console. Since "fonts.css" is the most commonly used file one can choose not to load this file for url showing graph. This removes the error and loads the graph.

Comment: how do u not choose to load it ?